# Need help converting java.stream to list

Tags: java, list

I cant for the life of me understand how to convert this code, I used streams to build a list for something called CARDINAL_NEIGHBORS.. But my professor decided to change the signature and instead of allowing us to use streams we cant.. I have tried building a list using function and lambda combo but it doesnt seem to work, Can anyone help me through this ? I need to pass in the constant CARDINAL_NEIGHBORS to a computepath method for a AStar pathing strategy...

So this is what i originally had ...

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface PathingStrategy
{
    /*
     * Returns a prefix of a path from the start point to a point within reach
     * of the end point.  This path is only valid ("clear") when returned, but
     * may be invalidated by movement of other entities.
     *
     * The prefix includes neither the start point nor the end point.
     */
    List<Point> computePath(Point start, Point end,
                            Predicate<Point> canPassThrough,
                            Function<Point, Stream<Point>> potentialNeighbors);

    static final Function<Point, Stream<Point>> CARDINAL_NEIGHBORS =
            point ->
                    Stream.<Point>builder()
                            .add(new Point(point.x, point.y - 1))
                            .add(new Point(point.x, point.y + 1))
                            .add(new Point(point.x - 1, point.y))
                            .add(new Point(point.x + 1, point.y))
                            .build();
              }
```

///-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

And This is what i need now ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


interface PathingStrategy {
/*
 * Returns a prefix of a path from the start point to a point within reach
 * of the end point.  This path is only valid ("clear") when returned, but
 * may be invalidated by movement of other entities.
 *
 * The prefix includes neither the start point nor the end point.
 */
List<Point> computePath(Point start, Point end,
                        Predicate<Point> canPassThrough,
                        Function<Point, List<Point>> potentialNeighbors);
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collectors.toList` to collect the contents of the stream to a list.

```
point -> Stream.<Point>builder()
            .add(new Point(point.x, point.y - 1))
            .add(new Point(point.x, point.y + 1))
            .add(new Point(point.x - 1, point.y))
            .add(new Point(point.x + 1, point.y))
            .build()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above returns `Function<Point, List<Point>>`

You can also use `Stream.of(...).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1):

No need stream also you can use lambda like this.

```
static final Function<Point, List<Point>> CARDINAL_NEIGHBORS =
  point ->
  {
    List<Point> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Point(point.x, point.y - 1));
    list.add(new Point(point.x, point.y + 1));
    list.add(new Point(point.x - 1, point.y));
    list.add(new Point(point.x + 1, point.y));
    return list;
  };
```